# Why do we need Monad Transformers in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

My understanding is the following:

Suppose `M1` and `M2` are monads, i.e. they provide functions `unit` and `flatMap` that comply to the monadic laws. Unfortunately we *cannot* create `unit` and `flatMap` for `M1[M2]` . It looks like the `unit` and `flatMap` don't *always* exist for *any*  `M1` and `M2`. I do not know if we need to prove it.

So the solution is to create a *wrapper* `W` for `M1[M2]`, so that `W[M1, M2]` *is* a monad, and use it instead. This wrapper `W` is called *Monad Transformer*.

Do I understand it correctly ?

Comment: Quick hand-wavy answer: monads don't compose in the general case, but sometimes specific monads do, and monad transformers provide a way to make that composition happen. Note that a monad transformer is _not_ itself a monad—your summary is potentially ambiguous on this point.

Comment: @TravisBrown Thanks. I was sure a monad transformer _was_ itself a monad. Is `ListT` a monad, for example ? It seems to provide both `unit` and `flatMap`.

Comment: `ListT` is a monad once it's been applied to a monad, so `ListT[Option, _]` is a monad (morally—that's of course not valid Scala syntax).

Comment: @TravisBrown Thanks. Now I got it. (I will fix the question)

Answer (score 3):

You are right. Typically they are used in for-comprehension constructions where you need to combine monads properties.

Monad transformers "step-by-step" [here](http://scala.org.ua/presentations/scala-functional-refactoring).

Comment: Thank you. I know your presentation. It's really great. I still didn't get it   but I will try (and ask questions here).